# time series plot on google earth using matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, google-earth

I have three sets of data:

1. time
2. longitude
3. latitude

I would like to plot this on google earth using google earth toolbox for matlab, what i need is when i move the time slider a line should be drawn on google earth.

I tried this

```
   x  = [longitude, latitude];
   y = time;
   kmlStr = ge_plot(x,y);
```

But an error occured.
On the other hand ge_gplot does not make sense for this.

Is there a way i can do this timeseries plot using google earth toolbox?

Comment: just my poor assumption here but shouldn't it be ge_plot(longitude,latitude) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two vectors: one for x (longitude), one for y (latitude).  `ge_plot(x,y)` will draw a line connecting each pair of `(x,y)` points in these vectors.

If you want to draw the line as a slider advances, then you need to make use of a callback function.  In this function, do `ge_plot(x(1:ind), y(1:ind) )` where `ind` is determined by the "time" value of the slider.